# Prolog variable not seen inside conditional clause

Tags: debugging, prolog

I am working on a project in Prolog and I stumbled upon a problem:

Let's say I am working with a list `[H|T]`.

```
    function1(H,T),
    check(H,T,Result),
    Result= 'Yes' -> 
        Stuff
        ;

         function2(H,T,NT),
                     Stuff2...

    )
    ; 
    Stuff3.
```

My problem is that it seems inside the conditional clause the `H` and `T` variables seem not to be visible (they are treated as new variables). My question is: how can I make them visible?

Comment: It's unclear to me what code you are showing. Is this inside of a predicate? There's also an unbalanced parenthesis. The `H` and `T` as shown should be "the same ones" through the sequence you're showing. You may need to explain more about what you're seeing.

Comment: Can you post a http://sscce.org/ ? Or at least the head of the rule?

Answer (score 5):

The way you have written it (making some assumption about the part you omitted), your code is interpreted as

```
( function1(H,T),
  check(H,T,Result),
  Result= 'Yes' -> 
    Stuff
;

    function2(H,T,NT),
    Stuff2...
)
```

which would lead to the effects of function1 being undone before function2 executes.  Maybe what you wanted was

```
function1(H,T),
check(H,T,Result),
(  Result= 'Yes' -> 
    Stuff
;

    function2(H,T,NT),
    Stuff2...
)
```

The comma binds stronger than the semicolon, so always use parentheses around an if-then-else or a disjunction, and make sure they have the correct scope.

Comment: Good catch (+1). In the first case, without parenthesizing the "if-then-else" clause, Prolog will backtrack if `Result = 'Yes'` fails and won't do the "if" until `check` produces `Result` of 'Yes'.